# Guidance for vuejs SPA application and prerendering (+ sitemap)

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, sitemap, prerender

I have read a lot of articles about the prerendering and how to implement it in vue js application.
I have successfully used https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin/ on my  vuejs application.  After some pain with the config, I have now several [routename].html files (Hourra o/).

But now I m a little lost. 
**I m looking for general guidance (how to)**.

Prerendenring pages should be used for clients (because it s html and it will be speed up but then how to switch to vuejs client page?) or only for crawlers (as googlebot) ?
If a crawler try to access to a page should I redirect it to the prerending page ?

One other question : Should I add these prerendering pages to my **sitemap** or not ?

Answer (score 1):

So far I got it prerendering SPA pages is for SEO reasons in the first place. If you don't prerender the search engine bots can't crawl the content which is generated by javascript when calling the page with a browser. The prerendred pages have to be uploaded to your server and linked in your sitemap. The bot (not supporting js) will call the prerendered html page. If you call the page with your browser having js enabled - the javascript-file (that is loaded in the prerendered pages as well as long you have js enabled) will take over and rerender the page.

Remember you might need a .htaccess file to map the route-paths to the rerendered files.
Could look like:

```
# .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I just tested this for the first time and got it to work like that. In my setup
I had this file structure in my dist folder:

```
index.html
    about/index.html
    work/index.html
    etc.
```

with matching routes in my app

```
/
/about
/work
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have an identic scenario.  I use prerendered page for seo (so that target bots crawler). But for 'human' user i cannot use prerendered page because of one issue.  Indeed, the js doesn t take over the page.  I see my UI with a correct html but the page looks like to be not reactive anymore (links are broken and don t trigger navigation, any click trigger do nothing)... So for a human user i use the "empty" index.html (auto generated by vue) where the view is dynamically created by the js.

Comment: Did you check in sourcecode if js and css files should be loaded? And how do you check the prerendeted pages? In my case it works only when having the pure slug in my url like domain.com/work without specifying index.html

Comment: Just to be sure : If your url (in the browser address bar) is https:// domain.com/about => the browser load the root /index.html (generated by vue) then load all bundle js files (/js/app.xxx.js, /js/chunk-vendor.xxx.js, ..) all css files (/css/chunk.xxx.css) and then vue js process the file, navigate to /about path and then render the view.  In other words, the prerendered file is not used for a human user no ?

Comment: Reply part 1:
To be sure I prerendered all routes and added a comment in the end of every HTML file for further investigation. And it works like: if you call website.com/about the browser renders the index.html inside the about directory.

Comment: Reply part 2:
If you disable js in your chrome console you get the prerendered content. If js is enabled vue is "taking over" and you can navigate through your app/website normally. Inspecting the source via chrome console shows that that HTML file does not change when navigating (js enabled) - so that shows that js is taking over routing right while the page does not reload. So all js files and css files are loaded in the prerendered HTML files.